# Docker container and mysql container connection error

Tags: docker, containers

I am new to docker. I need to connect mysql separate container with tomcat another separate container. So first I pull the docker image by using

> docker pull mysql

After that I try to run the image and run the database container by the following command.

> docker run --name easql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=1234 -d mysql

after that I create a database by running the following commands.

> docker exec -it easql mysql -uroot -p

Then run the mysql command to create a database called custom.
After that I created a folder and make a Dockerfile and webapp folder. In my webapp folder I created the folder called db1.jsp file my db1.jsp file is following.

```
<%@ page import="pageNumber.*,java.util.*, java.io.*, java.sql.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
    <%

    try {
      java.sql.Connection con;
      Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver");
      con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://db:3306/custom", "root", "1234");
      out.println ("database successfully opened.");
    }
    catch(SQLException e) {
      out.println("SQLException caught: " +e.getMessage());
    }
  %>
</body>
```

And my Dockerfile is following

```
FROM tomcat:8-jre8
COPY ./webapp /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/webapp
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

and my folder structure is following.
[image]

My context.xml file is following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <Resource
        name="jdbc/custom" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" 
        url="jdbc:mysql://db:3306/custom"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        username="root" password="1234"
    />
</Context>
```

After that I build this application by go to inside the folder and run the following commands

> docker build -t 123adw .
>
> docker run --name hello -p 4000:8080 123adw

After that I make the link between the application by the following command

> docker run --name connection --link easql:mysql -d 123adw

But when I run the http://localhost:4000/webapp/db1.jsp its give me the following error.

> SQLException caught: Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

anyone can help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you working with multiple containers try to use [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/) its much easier. try below docker compose file you might need to change little bit but you will get the idea.

Both `mysql-db` container and the `web-app` containers are in same network `app_net`. So inside you `web-app` you can call the mysql container as `mysql-db` with port `3306`( and exposing `8002` port to the host)

```
version: '2'
services:
    web-app:
        build: ./webapp # put your web app in /webapp folder in this folder must have the Dockerfile for the webapp
        ports:
        - "4000:8080"
        restart: always
        working_dir: /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/webapp
        networks:
        - app_net

    mysql-db:
        container_name: mysql-db
        restart: always
        image: mysql:8.0
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root'
            MYSQL_USER: 'root'
            MYSQL_PASS: 'root'
        volumes:
        - ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql # create this(mysql-data) folder for persisting data of the mysql in your host
        ports:
        - "8002:3306"
        networks:
        - app_net

networks:
    app_net:
        driver: "bridge"
```

Comment: I try this but when I run docker-compose up I got error "Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: Dockerfile"

Comment: You should create a webapp folder and put you webapp content their with the Dockerfile

Comment: Using this docker-compose is it creating another container called easql (mysql) or use already created easql container

Comment: Stop you current easql container and run docker-composer. It will create a container called `mysql-db`

Comment: Sorry its trying to creating mysql-db but stuck there

Comment: Please create the mysql-data folder in the same folder as docker-compose

Comment: I tried this but I got this error  now "Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server." thank you for your comments

Comment: can you login into the running mysql container and see `/etc/mysql/my.cnf or /etc/my.cnf` wether it has `bind-address="127.0.0.1" or bind-address="0.0.0.0` restriction?

Comment: I found my error thanks @Ntwobike but this answer not work for me I create another docker-compose using your answer thank you